# parsing Jsoup not working

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am trying to parse the hot topics from google trends in this [link](http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/hourly)

I tried doing this but the elements size are always 0..

```
     Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

            if (doc != null) {

                Elements elements = doc..select("li");
                for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
                    String strValue  = elements.get(i).select("a").text();
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is, you cannot parce the content properly. You can use this:

```
    if (doc != null) {
         Elements elements = doc.select("content");
         for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
             Element element  = elements.get(i);
             Document doc2 = Jsoup.parse(element.text());
             Elements liElements =  doc2.select("li");
             for (Element liElemet : liElements) {
                 String strValue  = liElemet.select("a").text();
             }   
         }
     }
```